# '\r' added to end of everything input in python

Tags: python-3.x, notepad++

im new to the site and programming so i apologise in advance if my question ends up being very obvious to answer. I'm using notepad++ and python 3.2.

So my question is why is there now a '\r' and/or a '\n' added to the end of every input i make in the python console when running and testing my program? I've been searching the internet for an answer for days and the closest i've come to a cause of the problem is that it could be that python is recognising the return key as a character to be added to the string input. I found that this could be that i am coding in what's called 'text mode'.

I've tried encoding the program in a different format but with no luck. My next thought was to try it on a different machine and it worked as it should, with the string in the input's variable not containing either '\r' or '\n'. Following this i decided to un-install and re-install python and notepad++ (and any leftover files) to see if the problem lied there. But again, it made no difference.

Here is my code. it's made a basic chat program which reads, writes and saves to a csv file which was working until recently when i started having this problem (when working on another program).

```
def get_info():
    #get name and a starting message from the user
    name = input("what is your name? >")
    note = input("what say you? >")
    output = ">" + name + ">" + note + "\n"
    return(output)

def save_file(the_message):
    #this function appends the new message to the group list
    #needs argument to write (the_message is the argument)
    #returns nothing
    hard_drive = open("C:\\Users\Harry\Documents\Homework\A Levels\Computing\chat.csv", "r")
    hard_drive.write(the_message)
    hard_drive.close()

def read_file():
    message_file = open("C:\\Users\Harry\Documents\Homework\A Levels\Computing\chat.csv", "r")
    #"r" means read
    printable = message_file.read()
    message_file.close()
    return(printable)

while True:
    #calls get_info function in
    print_message = get_info()
    save_file(print_message)
    #saves return value of get_info
    messages = read_file()
    #calls in read_file and creates variable in which return value is copied
    print(messages)
    #return value of read_file is printed
```

it seems to only occur in a function and it is the same in every other program (that was working) i've made. Here's what i get in the console when i call the function after running the program:

```
>>>getinfo()
what is your name? >random
what say you? >anything
'>random\r>anything\r\n'
```

(return of the function is the bottom line - would like to have posted a pic but im a new user)
I suspect it's a problem with my operating system (windows 8) - anyone have any ideas?

Edit: the program i was working on when i noticed the problem:

```
print("Address Book v2.6.9 \n")
print("This program will allow the user the add and search for users addresses \n")

def read_file():
    file_handle = open("C:\\Users\Harry\Documents\Homework\A Levels\Computing\Python\dataoct_24_2014.csv")
    #file is opened and read from, reference held in variable
    read = file_handle.read().splitlines()
    #variable 'read' holds reference to method which returns all lines from file as list of lists
    all_addresses = []
    for address in read:
        split_fields = address.split("|")
        all_addresses.append(split_fields)
        #this should make it easier when reading a writing by making a list
    #returns a list of lists containing strings, all separated by commas
    file_handle.close
    return all_addresses

def index():
    #this will determine the index number for new people added to the address book
    #read_file()
    contact_index = (len(read_file()))
    #assigns no. contacts the reference to number of lines in file
    return contact_index

def get_add_info(first, last, number):
    contact_index = index()
    #could make a function that assigns each new address with it's correct index
    formated_info = str(contact_index) + "|" + first + "|" + last + "|" + str(number)
    #remember to add \n to end when writing to file
    return formated_info        

#def search_file(user_input)

#def append_to_file(add_person):

while True:
    user_option = input("Type 'search' to search for a contact or 'add' to add a new contact to your address book: ")
    #other options will be created later
    if user_option == "search":
        print("(this will work later)")
    elif user_option == "add":
        print("Please enter new contact details: \n")
        first_name_input = input("Enter first name of person: ")
        last_name_input = input("Enter last tame of person: ")
        phone_number_input = input("Enter phone number of person: ")
        get_add_info(first_name_input, last_name_input, phone_number_input)
    else:
        print("Have you spelt you choice correctly?")
```

Comment: Windows often ends lines with \r\n and Python should change \r\n to \n, which is not included in the string returned by input().  I don't know how you changed that from working.  Do you have the same problem with `>>> input("x: ')`? Have you tried running Python as another user on the same machine?

Comment: thanks for the fast reply and yes, i still get this problem. i haven't tried running it on a different user yet - i will try now

Comment: #i made a test program on my guest account as follows:      

variable_1 = input("input: ")

def get_info():
    variable_2 = input("input: ")
    return variable_2

        #the return of the function the only time im presented with this problem it seems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, "[the (backslash) character encodes difficult-to-type characters into a string](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex10.html)". Processing the backslash character encoding is called **escaping**.

The `print()` function **uses escaping**. The `return()` function **does not use escaping**, it outputs the **raw string**.

For example:

```
>>>string = "hello\n"
>>>def test(input):
       return(input)
>>>test(string)
'hello\n'
>>>print(string)
hello
```

The reason that this problem does not occur in your main script:

- `messages` contains the raw string from `get_info`
- you used the `print()` function on `messages`

Since you used the `print()` function on `messages`, `messages` will be displayed using **escaping**.

Why you have them in the first place:

- you explicitly added `"\n"` to your string in `get_info()`
- Python uses different line ending conventions, depending on your
  operating system, when writing to a file

Mac OS based computers follow the ["CR"(carriage return aka '\r') convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline). This means the strings, written to the csv file, will include the `"\r"` line ending.

Now why `get_info()` specifically shows/inserts the line endings, I am not sure; I would need more information from you but it sounds like an issue with your Notepad++ settings.

You could use write a function to remove extra escape characters. For example, you can use`rstrip()`.

Comment: thanks for all the information - helped me understand python a bit more (i would up vote but i don't have enough rep). The reason why it is such a problem to me is that it does effect the rest of my script in other programs also. for example in an 'if' statement in another program, the code which follows is executed if the input variable contains a certain word. Now because it contains '\r' that code cannot be executed but it is not equal the text it supposed to.

Comment: and the other machine i tested it on was running windows 7 and the same version of python and did not have this problem. if it helps i can post the code from the current program i am working on, which where i first noticed the problem. i think this is where it would've originated.

Comment: Good to know, I will do some more research for you. Post the code from the current program as well, that would be helpful. Does this issue occur when you define and run your get_info () function in the python ide too or only when you use notepad++? Also try to create a function to remove the extra characters in the mean time.

Comment: thanks, i'll add the code for the address book i'm making (current program) to the end of the question - its unfinished, it's only the read_file() function and While True statement i'm working on at the moment.

Comment: I ran the same function in IDLE and it doesn't put '\r' on the end of each input which means the problem must be with either notepad++ or the python shell.

Comment: Probably some setting in notepad++ then. I personally recommend using [Sublime text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2). Download it and try it out, see if it resolves your issue; it is a quicker fix and, I think, better text editor.

Comment: everything working now - well, except for other bugs, which i can sort. i'm using the text editor you recommended. i do prefer notepad++, mainly for the PyNPP plugin but im not too fussed. i'll have a look round and see which other text editors work best for me. thanks again

Comment: Sublime text allows you [to build and execute python script as well](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ZpuwW-9T54). You can also find very many useful plugins and install them using [Package Control](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oV0P_Y1SWuQ).

Comment: i've been trying to install sublimeREPL but having a few problems so theres still some uncertainty as to whether the i'll get the same problem in this text editor. i'll let you know when i finally test it.

Comment: everything working now - uninstalled python then reinstalled a different version (instead of the same version - which i'd tried before) and restarted my computer. Must had been a problem with python itself - who knows. thanks for all the help.