# "\r" added to user inputs in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, python-2.7, escaping

Very new to Python, VS code, and this site, so please let me know if you need more detail to help!

Using Windows 10
Python V 2.7.14
Latest version of VS code
Using Microsoft Python extension with Don Jayamanne extension

A similar version of this question has already been asked and answered:

['\r' added to end of everything input in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26790547/r-added-to-end-of-everything-input-in-python)

but it didn't seem to help other than to review that "\" is an escape character, and there was some problem with his setting in notepad ++. I wasn't able to figure out how I can fix this on my machine.

Here's a bit of code I wrote to show the problem

```
user = raw_input ("Enter string: ")

print user

if user == '1':
    print user
elif user == '1\r':
    print "Returned 1\r"
else:
    print "Failed"
```

I input 1. This, when run, prints 1, and then prints "returned 1". When I hover over the variable user, it shows as '1\r'. Clearly print isn't bothering with the \r part, but I can't use if/elif/else commands with user inputs, because \r is always added.

How do I keep \r from being added to user inputs, or is this supposed to happen for some reason?

I have already tried uninstalling and reinstalling both VS code and Python, and restarting my computer.

Thank you so much!

Comment: is the code inside a function??

Comment: You can use `strip` to remove whitespace including CR.

Comment: That's strange. I wonder if stdin is in binary mode. Can you check what command VS Code is using to launch Python?

Comment: Are you using `-u` command line option (binary)? https://bugs.python.org/issue21946

Comment: a) why are you using Python 2.7? It's 2018, everyone should be using Python 3 as it's the version that's being developed right now, that's the future of Python; b) run your code from the command line; if it works the way you expect it to work, trash VS Code and find a better IDE (like PyCharm or something); it shouldn't be adding `'\r'` by default.

Comment: 1. Does the `if/elif/else` block always return `"Failed"`? 2. Does the issue go away when you do `user = str(raw_input ("Enter string: "))`?

Comment: Thank you everyone for the fast replies! I'm extremely new at this so not sure how to access some of the info (like if Python is using the binary command line and how it's being launched) but it sounds like my best bet is using Python 3 (which doesn't seem to have the bug) and a better text editor.