# Converting a csv file generated in jupyter notebook into list of tuples

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

i am doing an exercise on the candidate elimination algorithm. I got a JSON file, i converted it to csv file using the following code

step 1:
`pdobj=pd.read_json('xxx.json', orient = 'records') print(pdobj)`

step 2:
`csvData=pdobj.to_csv(index=False) print(csvData)`

However when i am trying to convert this file into list of tuples i am getting errors i dont want to save the file in my disk then import it again. I just want to convert the csv file i generated directly into list of tuples.

this code landed me in error

```
with open (csvData) as csvfile:
      examples =[tuple(line) for line in csv.reader(csvfile)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) function takes the CSV file name as a parameter but not the CSV data itself. So, there is no need to read the CSV data again as it is already available as a string in the `csvData` variable.

To convert the CSV data into a list of tuples, use the following code. The conversion part was adopted from this Stack [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16449189/15745884).

Input JSON file:

```json
[
  {"Series":"I", "X":10.0, "Y":8.04},
  {"Series":"I", "X":8.0, "Y":6.95},
  {"Series":"I", "X":13.0, "Y":7.58},
  {"Series":"I", "X":9.0, "Y":8.81},
  {"Series":"I", "X":11.0, "Y":8.33}
]
```

```py
# Start of your code

pdobj=pd.read_json('sample_data/anscombe.json', orient = 'records') 
print(type(pdobj)) 

csvData=pdobj.to_csv(index=False, header=False) # I have skipped the header of the CSV
print(type(csvData))

# End of your code


# Convert the CSV data to a list of tuples
lot = [tuple(line.split(",")) for line in csvData.split('\n')]
print(list_of_tuples)
```

Output of the above code:

```
[('I', '10', '8.04'), ('I', '8', '6.95'), ('I', '13', '7.58'), ('I', '9', '8.81'), ('I', '11', '8.33')]
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the prompt answer. But i want to split into seperate strings in tuple not a single string. The output must look like this [('I',10','8.04',), ('I','8','6'.'95',), ('I','13','7'.'58',), ('I','9','8.81',), ('I','11','8.33',)] not like this [('I,10,8.04',), ('I,8,6.95',), ('I,13,7.58',), ('I,9,8.81',), ('I,11,8.33',)]

Comment: Hi @JChan. I have updated my answer based on your requirement. Consider accepting the answer (by clicking the "tick") if it helped.

Comment: Hi, everything is fine except that while using the code i am getting /r for the last row Here, the example >> [('med', 'med', 'med', 'high', 'high', 'med', 'med', 'med', 'True\r'),
 ('med', 'high', 'med', 'low', 'high', 'med', 'med', 'high', 'True\r')

Comment: Hi, can you create a new question for this issue? Because different requirements have to be addressed by different questions as per Stack Overflow guidelines.
Before creating a new question, be sure to check Stack if your requirement already has a solution. Otherwise, your question would be closed as a duplicate of the older question.

Comment: This Stack thread should be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26790547/r-added-to-end-of-everything-input-in-python